# Unresolved class in manifest

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, class, android-manifest

I got several classes in my manifest where Android Studio says ... unresolved class ...

but activities exists - no error in name

but they are connotated with

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
```

Has it something to do with it and what does this mean?